# 18.04 updates absent

Tags: updates, 18.04, repository, beta

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 when it was in beta. Everything worked well, updates were available almost every day, and I installed them.

Some time ago (around two weeks ago I'd say) updates when I ran `sudo apt update` stopped coming. I tried the new kernel (4.16) but then reverted to 4.15.0-20-generic . Some proprietary apps (google chrome, sublime text) no longer update, even though packages are always up to date. Ubuntu base, etc. is never available for update, and I'd say that the problem is in my installation/repos, since I know that updates are available to other people. I tried setting to download from main server, but still nothing.

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: There have not been a whole lot of updates since it is now a stable release. Are there specific updates you know exist but which are not showing as available? Otherwise it just sounds like you're expecting development pace for a stable release, which is just not the case.

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list (only uncommented parts)

`
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse ` @hiigaran